# Use logged in username as field value in django

Tags: python, django

How do I use the logged-in user's username as a default (and not editable) value in a django field?

For example, suppose I'm trying to log items purchased by a team of people.
I'm using `contrib.admin` as it seems to suit most of my needs.
I define a purchased line item like this:

```
class LineItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor)
    buyer = <whoever logged this purchase>
    date_ordered = models.DateField('date ordered', null=True)
    date_delivered = models.DateField('date delivered', null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(null=True,
        max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

How do I turn `<whoever logged this purchase>` into something that defaults to the name of the logged-in user?

P.S. I think another way to phrase this question is: where in the continuum of view->database should I get the user's name and store it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use User model as foreign key in the LineItem model as buyer.Whenever you are saving data in LineItem model, in that view,you can get request.user as the logged in user and store it as the buyer of that LineItem Object.

In LineItem model class

```
buyer = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In the view class/function of creating/updating a Lineitem object (in the post method) you can do

```
a_lineitem_object.buyer = request.user
a_lineitem_object.save()
```

Comment: Ah, of course. This is obvious now. I guess I need to figure out how to modify the views that contrib.admin is making for me. Is there a standard way to point the ForeignKey at the registered users? It seems weird to duplicate that information in another table.

Comment: [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) - here you can find how to filter out the registered users from all users and then use it in your LineItem model.